# Excel, using "Solver" with BINOMDIST, COMBIN()

Tags: probability

The question is:

How often do you have to toss a coin to ensure that the probability of at least 3 tails is greater than 0.97?

Using the Excel BINOMDIST function, this works out to be 
1- BINOMDIST(2,n,0.5,true) (i.e. 1-P(k≤2)) where "n" is the number of tosses required.

I use the following formula in Excel: 1-BINOMDIST(2,L1315,0.5,TRUE) in cell D1315 and a guess for "n" in cell "L1315".

Set target cell to D1315 to min value of 0.97 by changing L1315. The solver chokes on this, while goal seek works. Is this a known problem with solver?

I also have problems using Solver and Goal seek with the COMBIN() function. For instance if I have an equation (xC2)/(30C2) = 0.3 and I want to find the value of "x", both Solver and Goal Seek fail to find the solution which is ~ 17. I am using Excel 2003

Comment: You're likely to have problems with using a method like Solver to solve a discrete problem.

Answer (score 0):

Initial attempt at answer:

> Use "Evolutionary" rather than the other options. You'll need to set
>   lower and upper bounds for $n$. I set $1<n<100$.
>
> I set another cell to ABS(D1315-0.97) and minimised that cell - aim
>   for zero.

Second attempt at answer:

I think that the Solver is having problems with the COMBIN() function because it is discrete. Some of these solver engines inspect the function a little bit either side of the existing value to try to identify the slope of the function so that they can determine in which direction to head as they try to attain the required value.

One way forward is to abandon the COMBIN() function completely. You should know that COMBIN$(n,2)= \frac {n(n-1)}2$, which is defined for all values of $n$ - not just discrete values.

Comment: "Evolutionary" is not available in Excel 2003 solver. I seem to have problems with the Solver and Goal Seek with all Excel functions that are associated with Probability calculations. A Google search for possible explanations has not turned up much information.

Comment: From Excel help:   COMBIN
 
Returns the number of combinations for a given number of items. Use COMBIN to determine the total possible number of groups for a given number of items. "PERMUT() gives nPr?

Comment: My mistake with COMBIN function - fixed